# How do I ignore failed sonar runner uploads in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I see this error in my build scripts occasionally:

```
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: The project is already being analysed.
```

Unfortunately these errors make the build fail, even if everything else is fine.

I'm happy to allow Sonar Runner to fail occasionally, so is there a way to ignore these failures in a Gradle build script?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this. Does "ignoreFailures = true" works within sonarRunner task?

Answer (score 3):

1. Apply plugin:'sonarqube'//the most recent sonarqube plugin for gradle
2. Create a task: task sonarAnalysis(description:'sonar analysis') {....}
3. Inside the created task find the 'sonarqube' task and assign the value to a local variable, this goes on the configuration block of the task.
4. Inside the doLast block of the created task add a try/catch block around the 'sonar.run()'
5. Inside the catch throw a StopActionException() this is going to show you the error message but the build status won't change.

   ```
   apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
   task sonarAnalysis(group:"Sonarqube") {
       //Configuration block
       Task sonarTask = project.getTasks().getByName('sonarqube')
       //Action block
       doLast {
           try {
               sonarTask.run()
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new StopActionException()
           }
       }
   }
   ```